# What is the assistant editor in Xcode used for?

Tags: xcode

Sorry I am still learning! Why would you need two editors if changes to one makes changes to the other? Wouldn't it be more useful to have two independent editors to test out changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple views in the same window have numerous advantages. If you have independent windows, they can get overlapped, causing you to click between them. With Assistant Editor, they are part of the same window, so there is no occlusion for the views when it is the top window.

Some examples:

- Compare older version of file with newer version of file. This can be incredibly helpful if the code is complicated and there is a subtle change (note a diff would do well here too)
- View one file which has code you need to copy into another file.
- View header file along with implementation file.
- View header or implementation file for method you are calling because you need deeper incite in the code and how it affects what you are doing.

Assistant Editor isn't for everyone. I'd say play around with it and see if it's for you.

Comment: Okay those reasons sound really useful. I actually didn't even think about the last three. Thanks!